Logic Test: Room 1
$\leftarrow$Part 2

The door clicks open and a light flickers on. In front of you, you see a shiny black floor, and you step onto it. However, you find that you have stepped into nothingness and you lose your balance, before falling into a pitch-black abyss.  When you finally hit the ground, you find that there is something bulging in your pocket where your phone was. Reaching your hand in there, it turns out that you phone was shattered by the fall. Surprisingly, you are still alright, without feeling hurt anywhere. As you sit up, there seems to be something you are sitting on. You move a bit, and finger the weird something, and it hits you: it's a button! In a frenzy of excitement, you press the button, but all that happens is that the light turns on. You are in a room with a yellow carpet, and white walls. At one end of the room there is a keypad with the alphabet on it, and a screen with four boxes, like $\square \square \square \square$.
You see a piece of paper next to you, saying

Hi there,
Congratulations on getting this far! There is also nothing of use in this letter. The only way out of this room is to key in the right password in the keypad at the end of the room, and I have placed a hidden bomb underneath the room, which I have programmed to blow up if you get it wrong.
My favourite slogan is: Artistic Cones Remain Over Silly Tame Indigo Cats. I know it makes no sense at all, you should be able to understand it.
Also, there are random stuff in the room you might want to read.
Good luck!

In order to see the random stuff this  person decided to scatter, you get up and decide to look in the corners of the room. However, as you take only one step, you fall over, finding you have slipped on a piece of paper. Simply out of curiosity, you decide to pick it up. It says: Words have artistic techniques.
Sighing, you see a piece of paper at the back of the room, reading: Impacted States. Tailored Hat Elements. Nitrous Escaping Xenophobia Tales. Which Order Reads Dumb? 
You suddenly have a vague idea of what is going on, so you walk over to the keypad. You see this piece of paper saying HHLBBCNOFNSMASPSCAPCSTVCM
You say, "This completely messes me up! What now?" Suddenly, you remember that you brought a backpack with your laptop in it, and you open your laptop and post this question. Now, the quesiton is: What is the password?  
Note (not hint)

You don't want to blow up. :-)


The answer is

 IRON

because

 the sheets' first letters spell out "What is the next word?"

and

 the sequence HHLBBC... is the first letters of the chemical elements, in order; the M at the end is for Manganese, and the next element is iron.


Yep, thank you for answering.
